# Rails Sql Query for MONTH AND YEAR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date

I'm trying to show sales transactions for the current month and year in my index view.
This is what I've put in my sales controller:

```
def index
 @sales = show_sales_for_current_month(@sales)
```

which uses this method in the SalesHelper

```
def show_sales_for_current_month(sales)
  sales = Sale.find(:all,
                  :conditions => ["MONTH(date) = ? AND YEAR(date) =?",
                                  Date.today.month, Date.today.year])
end
```

where date is a date data type.

but i'm getting the following controller error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: MONTH: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE (MONTH(date) = 4 AND YEAR(date) =2011)
```

I've looked around at posts and it seems like that is the correct function, so what am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL this works, but you are using SQLite3 so you need to modify your query to use the SQLite3 version of MONTH and YEAR, which means using the strftime function:

```
sales = Sale.find(:all,
  :conditions => ["strftime('%m', date) = '?' AND strftime('%Y', date) = '?'",
    '%02d' % Date.today.month, Date.today.year])
```

Comment: Thank you!  I don't get the error any more, but now no records are being listed on the index page, and I do have some that match the search criteria.  On the index page I'm using the usual scaffolded    <%= @sales.each do |sale| %> ...etc

Comment: You probably need to quote the month and year. I updated my answer with this.

Comment: Yes, this works now.  The last thing I have to figure out is how to get the strftime('%m',date) to match Date.today.month since the latter returns a single digit for months < 10

Comment: Got it to match by using Date.today.strftime('%m') and removing the quote from the ? associated with month.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Hey there, I have a gem called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star) which could help you with these kinds of queries. In your case you would only need to do this in your controller:

```
@sales = Sale.by_month
```

by_star takes care of working out what month and year it is, as well as the messy SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution... Worked great for me!

Answer (score 3):

The functions MONTH and YEAR do not exist in SQLite3. You can take an approach like this (taken from my current project):

model entry.rb:

```
  def self.all_entries_year(year, user_id)
    where('entries.user_id = :id', :id => user_id ).
    where(':first_day <= entries.date AND entries.date <= :last_day', { 
        :first_day => Date.new(year, 1, 1),
        :last_day => Date.new(year, 12, 31)
    }).
    order('date desc')
  end
```

EDIT:

Put this in your model: sales.rb  (I assume, it has the field date)

```
def self.show_sales_for_current_month(year, month)

  mydate = Date.new(year, month, 1)

  where(':first_day <= sales.date AND sales.date <= :last_day', { 
        :first_day => mydate,
        :last_day => mydate.at_end_of_month
  }).
  order('date')
end
```